# How to debug this Python code?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this assigment:

> write the python code for to check if a given word is a valid password or not. A password is said to be valid if
>
> 1)it begins with a letter
>   2)must contain a number
>   3)and must contain a character
>
> If valid print valid if invalid print invalid

Is the code given below the right code for the above question? Will this Python code work for the above question?

```
        a=input()
         s=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']       
        x=['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
        y=['~','!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','_','+',';','[']
        m=''
        n=''
        while (c<=len(a)):
        c=c+1
        for i in range(0,27):
         if(s[i]==a[0]):    
          for z in a:
            for l in range(0,11):
                if(x[i]==z):
                    for i in range(0,16):
                        if(y[i]==z):
                            m='valid'
                        else:
                            continue
                            n='invalid'

                else:
                    continue
                    n='invalid'
       else:
        continue
        n='invalid'
       print(n)
       print(m)
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: do you check your code ? if it's work you must get right result (c=c+1) in under while is in invalid index please edit it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> (IS THE CODE GIVEN BELOW THE RIGHT CODE FOR THE ABOVE QUESTION WILL THIS PYTHON CODE WORK FOR THE ABOVE QUESTION?? )

ANSWARE : no , you can compare your code with my writed code , **you have used unnecessary  neted loops** and lists and your code is not clearly unreadable

> how can i solve it?

see the below code :

```
a= str(raw_input("enter password "))


y=['~','!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','_','+',';','[']


if (a[0].isalpha()) and sum(c.isdigit() for c in a) and sum(a.count(i) for i in y):
  print " valid password"


else :
 print "wrong!"
```

> explaintion:

**note 1:**( a[0].isalpha() ) is equal to your alphabet list and i used it to set code shorter and more readable

**note 2:** 
sum(c.isdigit() for c in a) determine if your password has a number or not you can specify a range for your numbers which should exist in password for ex: 
sum(c.isdigit() for c in a) > 2 means if just 2 digit exist in your password , password is vald

Comment: Thanks for the help i am just a beginner hence i know only basic functions